# Downloading an HTML page on Android

Tags: android, android-nougat

Is there an Android app to download an HTML page to a folder on my smartphone?

I usually make a copy in PDF format but sometimes it does not get very good.

I would prefer this for free. Some SE sites have codes I like to save in PDF format, but sometimes the PDF file loses a few lines of these codes. Saving in HTML format would not have this problem.

An Offline Reader would be an acceptable option.

Comment: What features do you need? Just the plain HTML code, or also embedded elements like images (e.g. for "offline reading")? How much are you willing to pay – or must it be free of charge? Maybe one of the [Web Clippings](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_clipboard#group_44) or [Offline Reader](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_webbrowser#group_1118) (disclosure: Links go to my site) apps fits your needs?

Comment: I would prefer this for free. Some SE sites have codes I like to save in PDF format, but sometimes the PDF file loses a few lines of these codes. Saving in HTML format would not have this problem.

Comment: So you want just to save the HTML code – and not the referenced material like images, CSS, etc? And also still open: Would an offline reader be considered an acceptable solution?

Comment: Yes. Would be an option...

Comment: Strongly pulling at your nose (asking for the 3rd time): Shall it only save the HTML, or "the page as shown" (including images, styling etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Google Chrome Browser has option to save the page for offline viewing. In the menu, you can see a download option. For accessing the pages quickly, you could bookmark the page, edit its name and then download that page for offline viewing.

Comment: I tried but could not find where it is saved so I can remove it and send it to the notebook

Comment: @LCarvalho Even I tried searching for the file before writing the answer, but of no luck. I think I need to spend some more time on that. Deleting, you can do from the downloads section of the browser. I will update the answer if I find a proper solution.